# Justification for using <code> tags for class names and keywords in Javadocs?

Tags: java, javadoc

In its [style guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide), Oracle suggests to use the `<code>` tags in Javadocs the following cases:

- Java keywords
- package names
- class names
- method names
- interface names
- field names
- argument names
- code examples

I personally find the cases of 'class names', 'field names', and 'Java keywords' particularly cumbersome as you end up with descriptions that I find to be less readable. For example:

```
/**
* Returns <code>true</code> if <code>x</code> is greater than 
* <code>y</code> otherwise returns <code>y</code>.
*/
public Boolean greaterThan(int x, int y) { return (x > y); }
```

I realize that the above example is arbitrary in itself, but longer descriptions for more complex functions can ends up equally ugly.  I understand the goal is to make the description pretty in an IDE, but looking at the class' java file itself is painful.

I'm considering foregoing `<code>` tags except when the documentation will contain a full fledged code example.  Are there reasons to not do this that I'm missing?

Comment: I agree with you, and in general I think the standards of typography around computing generally are appalling, but the question isn't a good fit for SO, as it just basically solicits 'debate, argument, polling , or extended discussion'. Voting to close as not constructive.

Comment: I guess I could rephrase the question slightly; I realize I am walking a fine line.  That said, I am looking for specific reasons to shape my decision making, not a debate.  E.g. if you use `<code>` you will have x, y, and z benefits.

Comment: (Note you can use `{@code ...}` in place of `<code>...</code>` these days.)

Comment: and you can use <tt>true</tt> instead, which is better readable

Comment: If you use <code> you will get Courier. Period. There is no other effect. Whether that's a benefit is an entirely subjective question.

Answer (score 5):

- JavaDoc is for [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) (and the IDE). Nothing else. Make it as
  readable as possible, so use the code tag for what you listed.
- **Other code comments** should help understand the code. As it's only part of the code, and will only be seen together with the code no further markup is needed.

Example:

```
/**
 * This method returns <code>true</code> when the sun is shining.
 *
 * @param weather - A <code>package.name.Weather</code> implementation
 * representing the weather to be analyzed.
 * return <code>true</code> if the sun is shining, else <code>false</code>.
 */
public boolean isSunShining(Weather weather) {
    boolean result = false; // boolean variable for the result. Default is false.
    // some more code
    /*
     * Multiline comment w/o markup
     */
    return result;
}
```